# bootstrap-typeahead.js v2.3.2 from suggested option select option and open in new tab

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, typeahead.js

From suggested option, user will select option right click and open in new tab.

That way user will open multiple link in new tab.

This my source

```
  [
     {"field_name":"abc ","field_value":"10162"},
     {"field_name":"xyz ","field_value":"10135"},
     {"field_name":"pqr ","field_value":"10121"},
     {"field_name":"test","field_value":"10100"}
    ]
```

HTML

```
  <input type="text" name="company" id="company" data-provide="typeahead" class="x-large form-control typeahead" autocomplete="off" data-hidden="#companyID" data-url="http://example.com/ajax/getCompany">
```

Script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var Mapped = {};
        $(".typeahead").typeahead({

            source : function(query, process) {

                return $.getJSON(
                        this.$element.attr('data-url'),
                        {query: query},
                function(result) {
                    var Labels = [];

                    $.each(result, function(i, item) {
                        Mapped[item.field_name] = item.field_value
                        Labels.push(item.field_name)
                    });

                    return process(Labels);

                });

            },
            items     : 10,
            minLength : 2,
            matcher   : function(item) {
                //console.log(item);
                return item;
            },
            updater   : function(item) {
                //For the Label selected ( item ) get the value mapped from the mapping array and set it to hidden element
                //$('hiddenelment').val(countryMapped[item]);
                var hidden_id = this.$element.attr('data-hidden');
                $(hidden_id).val(Mapped[item]);

                return item;
            }
        });
```

});

Comment: Put hyperlink on typehead content

Comment: I will try and let you know.

Comment: I have added link in my source. But when i right click on my suggested option, right click not working

Comment: is this possible for jquery-ui?

Comment: Please show your HTML markup as well, and the javascript. The "code" you have provided seems to be the source of the typeahead only. Why right click?

Comment: @davidkonrad I have added script and html. right click required because  user want to open multiple links form suggested options in new tab.

Comment: plus one for refining the question per request.

Comment: Thanks all i found the solution. Check below answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution,
Oveload render function of typahead.js and added link find("Link here") in below code

```
      $(".typeahead").data("typeahead").render = function (items) {

            var that = this

            items = $(items).map(function (i, item) {
               i   = $(that.options.item).attr('data-value', item)
               i.find('a').html(that.highlighter(item))

                //console.log("Link : "+Mapped[item]);
                // Link here (my answer)
               i.find('a').attr("href","<?php echo base_url();?>/index/"+Mapped[item]);

               return i[0]
            })

            items.first().addClass('active')
            this.$menu.html(items)
            return this

       };
```